# Selenium WebDriver Primefaces checkbox inside datatable is not visible to selenium tests in firefox 24

Tags: java, selenium

We are having a datatable in Primefaces in which there are checkboxes. While running Selenium Webdriver test for Firefox checkbox, we are getting ElementNotVisible Exception even though the element is visible in the browser. This test is running properly with IE.
Kindly let me know what can be the issue.
Given below is the code for primefaces & Selenium Test :-

#### Selenium Test Case

```
@Test
public void testGroupViewButton()
{
    try {
        logger.info("Method testGroupViewButton");
        WebElement searchResultsDataTableElement = commonTest.findElementById("carTable"); 

        logger.info(" searchResultsDataTableElement "+searchResultsDataTableElement.isDisplayed());
        List<WebElement> dataRows=searchResultsDataTableElement.findElements(By.className("ui-widget-content"));
        logger.info("dataRows "+dataRows.size());
        WebElement chkBoxElement;
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.name(checkBoxName)));

        for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
        {
            commonTest.waitUntilElementLoads();
            System.out.println("Check Box is  "+dataRows.get(i).findElement(By.tagName("input")));
            System.out.println("Check Box is displayed "+dataRows.get(i).findElement(By.tagName("input")).isDisplayed());
            chkBoxElement = dataRows.get(i).findElement(By.name("carTable_checkbox"));

            System.out.println("chkBoxElement "+chkBoxElement);
            System.out.println("chkBoxElement "+chkBoxElement.isDisplayed());

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.trace(e);
    }
}
```

JSF Code:-

```
<ui:composition template="template/common/commonPrimefacesLayout.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
<p:button value="Test" onclick="checkVisibilityOfCheckBox()"></p:button>
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.cars}" paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{car.id}" selection="#{tableBean.selectedCars}" id="carTable">
<f:facet name="header">
 Checkbox Based Selection
</f:facet>
<p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="visibility: visible;width:20%;height:20%" />
<p:column headerText="Model">
<h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had frustrating issues with this problem. In the end I resolved using:

```
   JavascriptLibrary jsLib = new JavascriptLibrary(); 
   jsLib.callEmbeddedSelenium(driver,"triggerMouseEventAt", editButton,"click", "0,0");
```

editButton is a WebElement